# Keycloak docker Administration Console shows blank page with reverse proxy

Tags: docker, docker-compose, keycloak, haproxy

I am using HAProxy with Keycloak, welcome page is showing fine but each time I enter Administration Console it shows me a blank page with no info with status code 200.
I am using let's encrypt SSL certificate and here is my HAProxy config and docker-compose.

Screenshot of the page:-
[link to screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMgmy.png)

HAProxy config:-

```
global
    log stdout local0 debug
    daemon
    maxconn 4096

defaults
    mode    http
    option  httplog
    option  dontlognull
    timeout connect 5000ms
    timeout client 50000ms
    timeout server 50000ms

    log     global
    log-format {"type":"haproxy","timestamp":%Ts,"http_status":%ST,"http_request":"%r","remote_addr":"%ci","bytes_read":%B,"upstream_addr":"%si","backend_name":"%b","retries":%rc,"bytes_uploaded":%U,"upstream_response_time":"%Tr","upstream_connect_time":"%Tc","session_duration":"%Tt","termination_state":"%ts"}


frontend public
    bind *:80
    bind *:443 ssl crt /usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.pem alpn h2,http/1.1
    http-request redirect scheme https unless { ssl_fc }
    default_backend web_servers


backend web_servers
    option forwardfor
    server auth1 auth:8080
```

docker-compose.yaml :-

```
version: "3"
networks:
  internal-network:
services:
  reverse-proxy:
    build: ./reverse-proxy/.
    image: reverseproxy:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    networks:
      - internal-network
    depends_on:
      - auth

  auth:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest
    networks:
      internal-network:
    environment:
      PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING: "true"
      KEYCLOAK_USER: ***
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: ***
      # Uncomment the line below if you want to specify JDBC parameters. The parameter below is just an example, and it shouldn't be used in production without knowledge. It is highly recommended that you read the PostgreSQL JDBC driver documentation in order to use it.
      #JDBC_PARAMS: "ssl=false"
```

the URL to the page I am trying to access is https:///auth/admin/master/console/

Notes: when trying to remove SSL from HAProxy, the Keycloak opens a page with error "https required"

Answer (score 1):

One obvious issue (there can be more issues, so fix of this one may still not fix everything):
https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/index.html#_setting-up-a-load-balancer-or-proxy

> Configure your reverse proxy or loadbalancer to properly set X-Forwarded-For and X-Forwarded-Proto HTTP headers.

You didn't configure this part in your haproxy frontend section. You need that:

```
  http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port]
  http-request set-header X-Forwarded-For %[src]
  http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Proto https
```

Https protocol is required for OIDC, so "https required" is correct response, when you reach Keycloak via http protocol.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It solved my problem!! I appreciate it!

Comment: I had those, but was missing PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING: "true" from the docker-compose. Adding that solved this issue for me.